# Стилизация iframe из родительской страницы

Tags: html, css, iframe

Есть виджет коронавируса https://travelrept.ru/koronavirus-covid-19-vidzhety-dlya-sajtov.html
Красивый, работает, но есть маленькая проблема: встраивается в сайт как iframe и там сверху небольшая полосочка с ссылкой на ресурс.
Эта полосочка с белым фоном. А у меня сайт тёмный. И это белое пятно не вписывается в цветовую гамму сайта.
Как изменить цвет фона и текста во встраиваемом iframe? Это вообще возможно? Есть идеи?

Comment: Это невозможно, в этом весь смысл iframe. Это как бы окно в другой сайт, смотреть можно, менять нельзя.

Comment: Поиграйтесь с высотой iframe, может получится скрыть из зоны видимости